# How to output php sql function in html?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, function, foreach

I have a function in php which needs to display all records within the table. But I just can't seem to display them in HTML.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
function display_products(){
    $query = mysql_query("Select id, naam,prijs from product");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    return $data;
}?>
```

and here is my attempt to display the array of in my html:

```
<?php
$products = display_products();
foreach ($products as $product): ?>
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $product['naam'] ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $product['prijs'] ?></li>
  </ul>
}
<?php endforeach; unset($product); ?>
```

Comment: Can u show us the code for the function display_products()?

Comment: The code is displayed above in the first part

Comment: what is the output if you do a `var_dump($products)` immediately after `$products=display_products()`

Comment: output : array(0) { }

Comment: Sounds like you probably don't have a good database connection.

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("Select id, naam,prijs from product") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I get Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: There is no database connection. This is not necessarily bad because it's a good opportunity to get rid of those mysql_* deprecated functions and use mysqli_* instead.

Comment: @UgurErtas as one dutch to another: please learn to stay away from dutch names within code/databases. As soon as you're going to collaborate with someone not dutch you'll run into problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following (don't forget to change the constants in mysqli_connect() function). Also, if you get familiar with this try to use PDO.

```
<?php
function display_products() {
    //Connect to database
    $connection = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USER, MY_PASSWORD, MY_DATABASE);
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
    }
    //Make the query
    $query = "SELECT id, naam, prijs FROM product;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $data = array();
    //Fetch all the data
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    return $data;
}
?>


<?php
$products = display_products();
foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $product['naam']; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $product['prijs']; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This worked thanks :).  yeah exactly I shouldn't use mysql anymore could be dangerous in the long term